# Why must I restart my DSL modem every morning?

Tags: networking, adsl

I am troubleshooting a poor DSL connection. Most mornings I am unable to receive any internet traffic.

The problem is always solved by restarting the DSL modem (and never solved by restarting the wireless router it is connected to). If I don't restart the modem, the problem is often solved on its own by the afternoon.

This problem has presented with both an ISP provided modem and a replacement modem of a different brand which I purchased.

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: As a note, this question (http://superuser.com/questions/655451/why-is-resetting-an-adsl-modem-so-effective) asks a similar question to mine, but the answers assume the problem must be with the DSL modem itself. In this case, I'm pretty sure the problem is not specifically with the modem, since I have the same problem with two different DSL modems.

Comment: I would start by contacting your ISP. There could be an issue with your DSL signal.

Comment: Is it specific to restarting or does reconnecting (as in redial your DSL Connection) also do?. I have also seen a problem where Heat was the cause for connection drops. You cool the modem and it stays connected longer till it heats up. Also make sure you have high SnR ratio (especially in the morning or specifically the time when you lose connection).

Comment: Are you running torrents or some other process that creates large amounts of connections overnight?

Comment: @Paul: No. There's no (or virtually no) traffic overnight.

Comment: @AEonAX: I'm not sure how to "redial" my DSL connection. Should it be an obvious option in the modem's web interface?

Comment: Which modem are you using?

Comment: @AEonAX: The modem is a TP-LINK TD-8616.

Comment: Hmm. I checked the manual but found nothing about reconnection. But Found a `“Maintenance→SysRestart”`, Option. Maybe you can automate that?

Comment: *"How can I troubleshoot this problem?"* -- You need to gather the modem's transceiver statistics (DSL speeds, margin aka SNR, line attenuation, and transmit power) during the "normal" and "problem" times of the day.

Comment: @sawdust: Good advice. This led me to a solution. Do you want to expand your comment to an answer, perhaps expanding on what SNR margin, line attenuation, and transmit power mean and whether those numbers should be at certain levels or are relative in all installations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I troubleshoot this problem?

You should quantify any issues by gathering the modem's transceiver statistics during the "normal" and "problem" times of the day.  These numbers can be obtained by logging into the the modem's web pages using a PC's browser.

The salient statistics are the downstream and upstream numbers for:

- DSL speed in Kbits per second, is the performance number that is the typical end-user's primary concern.  Some modems will try to maintain this rate even under adverse conditions, while others may auto-reduce this speed in order to minimize error rates.
- margin aka SNR (signal to noise ratio) is a measurement of signal quality, and the measurement most likely to fluctuate.  A larger number is better.
- line attenuation is primarily a function of the wire length from the modem back to the telco's central office.  This measurement should be rather stable and consistent.  A smaller number is better
- transmit power is also closely related to the wire length, and should be rather stable.

Those are the basic statistics that should be displayed.  If there is more than this, then record those numbers also.  An ADSL modem issue will not be taken seriously without these numbers.

When the ADSL modem tries to establish a connection (after a power-on, reset or disconnection), it must perform a prescribed sequence with the DSLAM at the telco's central office.  This sequence is referred to as "training", and involves preset signals, handshaking and negotiation to establish power levels, equalization and the all-important connection speeds.  ADSL signals may span relatively long distances over low-quality wire (it's only small-gauge unshielded twisted-pair rather than coax), and thus suffer significant attenuation (reduction in signal level).  The time-consuming training period is to configure the transmit and receive electronics at each end for fast but reliable (low error-rate) communication.

In the face of changing (i.e. deteriorating) line conditions, I've seen ADSL modems take different approaches.  I've seen a modem try to "ride it out" by maintaining its configuration and speed in spite of increasing error rates. I've seen another modem that would compensate by reducing its speed as error rates increased; but the modem was very slow in restoring that lost speed.  In most cases the simplest remedy for an ADSL modem after an error storm is to force it to retrain (e.g. power cycle or dis/re-connect).

Assuming that you do not have a dry line, also check the voice quality of the phone line.  Over the years the static on my phone line increased to the point that even the service rep noticed it, and I had no problem in convincing them in fixing my ADSL issues.  The diligent lineman conditioned my line by removing a bridged tap and also rerouted my line using a shorter (by 1000 feet) wire pair to the CO.

Comment: Perfect. I observed that my SNR was quite low and speed very, very low once this issue occurred. My ISP's tech support commented on the poor SNR and sent a technician to inspect their lines. They found a problem and the issue is gone. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

In general there might be two reasons for restart of modem ,In Generic

Like other electronic devices, one of the biggest reasons you may benefit from rebooting your modem is because when you leave your modem on for too long, it will tend to stop performing at its best after a while.

Another reason is that when your modem is on all day, every day, it is slowly desynchronizing from the Internet Service Provider (ISP). This desynchronization causes the packets you are sending and receiving to become corrupt, requiring them to be resent, and thus, lowering your speed.

Comment: The idea of a modem "desynchronizing from an ISP" sounds like techno-jargon. In searching for the term, the second reference I found was an answer on another question that is very similar to your second paragraph (http://superuser.com/a/184389/12646). Perhaps you wrote it under a different user name? If so, could you me where you learned about it?

Comment: @Eric its quite surprising to me that both of the answers were same,let me know what u wish to know about desynchronization,i will clarify about it,cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be related to the DSL line or the modem. First, check for any scheduled maintenance or outages from your ISP. If the problem persists, it might be a modem or line issue. Contact your ISP to inspect the DSL line and consider testing with a different phone jack.