# Attenuation, SNR, wire from Demarcation box OK but ping request and traceroute/tracert hangs sometimes, for ADSL+

Tags: networking, router, internet, ping, adsl

I had an ADSL+ internet connection from a third party ISP (Internet Service Provider).

Attenuation was low. SNR (signal-to-noise) Ratio was Normal. I checked it with the tool(DMT) from the internet connecting a laptop directly to the modem and with Bell's technician separately. All were normal. No problem.

Multiplexer and Phone line is Bell's. After the multiplexer, my ISP deals with the data. But the carrier is Bell.

Still Signal dropped randomly. Upload and Download were very low as a turtle.

Sometimes out of 4 pings (icmp echo reply) requested 100% packet drops. Traceroute/tracert hanged sometimes not always. Overly long time for random hops. Changed the Demarcation Box. Changed wires from Demarcation Box to internal phone line junction using Bell's technician. Still no luck.

Changed Router three times. Netgear. DLink. Linksys. All in Bridged mode. Behind the adsl+ modem.

Used the numerical parameters that were supplied by the ISP for the modem.

Windows Network Sharing Center showed there is no problem with the home network. There is a cross mark from the internet to the router. I was using dynamically assigned IPs for the network. Also tried statically assigned IPs. Still nothing. Changed the modem. First had Speedtouch then changed to TP-Link modem. I had good antivirus software. Scanned and updated regularly. Checked for spyware, adware, malware, virus but the result is negative. Used two antiviruses. All computers are scanned regularly. Had the highest level of encryption (WPA2+AES) that time around for wifi. Each time I wanted to debug I restarted the computer where I will debug or did ipconfig /release ipconfig /renew Used netstat/nbstat to search for backdoor service with virus. Still nothing.

Canceled ADSL+ (Asymmetric Digital Subscriber Line). Have cable. Everything is fine now.

Now my question: What else could have I done? Did I leave anything unchecked?

Comment: It sounds to me like your challenges were at the physical layer.  Did you notice any correlation between the issues and weather or environment?  (e.g. windy = poor behavior, or very wet ground = slow Internet?)

Comment: All these problems started during the snowy season. Now that you asked me I remember now. Does that point to anything?

Comment: *"What else could have I done?"* -- Convince the ISP to send out a line-person to inspect and test (using [TDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-domain_reflectometry)) your line.  See https://superuser.com/questions/926124/why-must-i-restart-my-dsl-modem-every-morning/926857#926857

Comment: The problem is because the phone line is Bell's. Bell's technician has to deal with that. My ISP cannot do anything. So Bell's technician came with a gauge meter device like a calculator and checked everything. He said everything is fine. Three different line-men came.

Comment: It points to it being a problem outside of your control, possibly with the infrastructure (Bell's equipment / cables).  If the tech can come by when the problem is occurring (if it is that predictable, or if you can make sure they come by during the snowy season?).  However, your relationship is with your (now previous) ISP, so I would suggest sharing your data with them, and then tell them that you've already changed providers due to this issue, so it is up to them what they want to do about it.

Comment: I even told the previous ADSL+ provider to monitor the data transaction/connection between my end to ISP and ISP to my end for fifteen days. Still, they couldn't find anything.

Comment: If the *"gauge meter device"* can't do TDR, then it's not a sophisticated tester that can find the problem.  See my comment for https://superuser.com/questions/1253210/can-a-cheap-adsl-modem-router-be-responsible-for-frequent-disconnects-from-and-s#comment1841194_1253210 for technical article.

Comment: I agree with @sawdust here, insist on either a TDR or FLUKE networks cable analyser. "Attenuation was low. SNR (signal-to-noise) Ratio was Normal." What were the actual SNR readings? And what was the signal loss (attenuation) in Decibel please? This honestly sounds like a CLEC issue to me, your ISP is buying wholesale lines from "ma Bell", bell/Verizon are forced to sell these lines to competitive suppliers, and as a result they seem to be low priority on the main carrier agenda in my experience.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Bell sent a technician as they are the carrier for the internet and he brought a rectangular yellow device twice. I can't tell you the attenuation or SNR from the top of my head but the technician said it was in best condition. It was a digital device. I think it has input and/or output.